# How can I factorize $|z_1|^q z_1 - |z_2|^q z_2$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, factoring

Let $1\le q\le 2$. I would like to know that how I can factorize the following:
$$
|z_1|^q z_1 - |z_2|^q z_2 = \\(z_1 - z_2) (\text{ a function of } z_1, z_2, \overline{z_1}, \overline{z_2}, q ) + (\overline{z_1} - \overline{z_2})(\text{ a function of } z_1, z_2, \overline{z_1}, \overline{z_2}, q )
$$
Actually it can be done easily if $q=2$. I would like to know that it still holds for $1\le q\le 2$.

Comment: one of the quantity can be zero on the right hand side.